# tracking last page visted

Tags: php, mysql, session, analytics, web-analytics

I am trying to track visitors, who visits my website. I am using codeigniter for the development of the site. What i am interested in is to track the last visited page before they close the webpage. Is there anyways to do it?

What I have been thinking is to save their last visited page in session and then when they close save information in the database. What happens when user closes a browser or the website(tab in the browser) or when they click on the link (in the webpage) and is redirected to another website? does it send close connection request to the server?

What is the best way to keep track of it?

Also would like to mention the visitors are public and they cant login to the website. And also i am using google analytics but what to create a custom one for my website to get more accurate results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save/update a database entry on the current page they are loading. That way it doesn't even matter if their computer crashes it will still record the last page they were on. You could even restore them to the last place they were this way if they came back to the website later (if you needed this functionality).

Comment: thanks for the tip. i get approx 14k visitors & 42k pageviews every month. per day around 500-700 visitors, 1800 - 2300 page views. by writing page visit to database every time wont it affect performance?

Comment: Sure it will take a small hit but that is a very small/quick query to execute. If you do notice a performance issue and your server is struggling just post another question on alternative ways to handle this and we will try and get more creative on tracking methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the current page in the session for the user and when the session gets destroyed, you can get the last page visited by using [`session-set-save-handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

Also, because HTTP is Stateless, you will never get a close connection callback.

Comment: thanks, but how can i get it done? note visitors dont logout they close the website at their end. And session will get timeout after say 5mins. How can i write a code to check session expire in codeigniter?

Comment: and forgot to mention codeigniter is not using php session.

Comment: If you go thru the link, you can register a callback, say for close(), which will be called when the session times out. You can do the saving part in that callback.